# ClickOnce complete uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, uninstallation

If i uninstall clickonce application - user settings files stay where they were. What can i do if i want all users to update configurations? So that all users get default configuration(that is app.config) and not their custom one after another update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which user settings files are you talking about? If they are in the ClickOnce cache, all of the files should be removed when you uninstall.

This is done by the ClickOnce scavenger service, and doesn't always happen right away.

Comment: I mean that if ive installed the clickonce once and made some changes in usersettings section there, then that changes are returning even after i uninstall and clean install the software.

Comment: Can you check the ClickOnce cache and see if the files are left behind? It's in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\weirdfoldername\weirdfoldername\firstfourlettersofassembly...

Comment: after i delete all that files in 2.0 - it helps. Thats why ive asked about COMPLETE uninstall. Uninstall the program and delete settings in one go.

Comment: ClickOnce is supposed to remove all of the files in the deployment when the user uninstalls it. You're not the only one to see files left behind sometimes, though. If this is causing you serious angst, you'll have to handle it programmatically. Might want to use application settings instead of user settings -- they can't write over them, but they won't carry forward either.